# Does EPPlus support ConditionalFormatting for Pivot tables?

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, conditional-formatting, epplus

I am using [EPPlus](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus) to create a pivot table and now I am trying to use ConditionalFormatting on the pivot table and it simply doesn't seem to work.  I have taken the example from *[Three color scale example](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/wiki/Three-color-scale-example)* and am trying to apply it on the cells of the pivot table:

```
 var rng = worksheet.Cells["N3:Y88"];  // (This is the output of the pivot table)

 var cfRule = rng.Worksheet.ConditionalFormatting.AddThreeColorScale(rng);
 cfRule.LowValue.Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF63BE7B");
 cfRule.MiddleValue.Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFEB84");
 cfRule.MiddleValue.Type = eExcelConditionalFormattingValueObjectType.Percentile;
 cfRule.MiddleValue.Value = 50;
 cfRule.HighValue.Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFF8696B");
```

And there isn't any impact.  I use the same code on a set of regular cells and it works fine.   Does EPPlus support the ability to conditionalformat a pivot table?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in *[Pivot Table support in Conditional Formatting #399](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/399)*.

```
public static void AddConditionalFormattingToPivotTable(ExcelPivotTable pivotTable)
{
    var worksheetXml = pivotTable.WorkSheet.WorksheetXml;
    var element = worksheetXml.GetElementsByTagName("conditionalFormatting")[0];
    ((XmlElement)element).SetAttribute("pivot", "1");
}
```